# Node.js Promise setTimeout resolves quicker than expected

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code in Node.js.

```
const timeout = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

I'm trying to test this code with the following test:

```
it("Should wait for given time before resolving", async () => {
    const MS = 100;
    const start = process.hrtime();

    await timeout(MS);

    const diff = process.hrtime(start);
    expect(((diff[0] * NS_PER_SEC) + diff[1]) / 1000000).to.at.least(MS);
});
```

The problem is sometimes (rarely), this test fails:

```
Should wait for given time before resolving:

  AssertionError: expected 99.595337 to be at least 100
  + expected - actual

  -99.595337
  +100
```

Obviously this is some type of timing issue with Node.js or something. If anything I expect `await timeout(MS);` to take slightly longer than `MS`. In no case do I expect it to take less time.

What is it about the internals of JavaScript/Node.js that causes this to happen?

This occurred on macOS 10.14.3 running Node.js version 8.15.1.

Comment: Is there a reason you're testing this? I can see testing to make sure that `timeout` creates a promise and calls a stubbed out `setTimeout` with the correct params, but it's not your responsibility to ensure the behavior of a core feature like setTimeout.

Comment: @NicholasTower It's still logic I'm writing. It would be a dumb mistake, but if I ever were to put `ms / 2` instead of just `ms` or not actually call `resolve`, I'd want to try to have my tests catch it. Obviously those are dumb situations, but to me, the more tests the better. Even if it is irrelevant, I think the question itself is still relevant. How do I know `setTimeout` is really working if I'm getting this inconsistent behavior? So in some regard the test proved at least a bit useful and is causing me to dig deeper. Which IMO is valuable.

Comment: What OS are you running the test on? Perhaps the underlying syscall is to blame: https://frenchfries.net/paul/dfly/nanosleep.html

Comment: @ııı macOS 10.14.3

Comment: @NicholasTower I'm still trying to wrap my head around mock functions. They seem dangerous because they really change the behavior of how things work. How can you verify that you aren't using a mock function or something in production by accident?

Comment: @CharlieFish The point of mocks are to focus your tests on one function at a time. If i'm writing a test around code that makes an http request, i just want to make sure i initiated that call with the right params. Whether the webservice happens to be online right now is irrelevant to the test. And similarly if i'm writing a test that sets a timeout and wraps it in a promise, i just want to make sure it initiated that with the right parameters. (PS, i have no objection to you wanting to understand the underlying behavior of setTimeout -- my only objection is to the usefulness of the test)

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce this in Chrome. Although there is wild variation in *actual* (in one case 104.97ms), it never went below ~100.2ms for me. So this seems specific to Node.js's `setTimeout()` implementation

Comment: @ııı Trying to reproduce in browsers would be difficult. Some of the reasoning why is documented on [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) as an example. Browsers will typically *"lag"* as a *"security measure"*

Comment: FWIW too, you can see it at work [here](https://repl.it/repls/ZanyHumiliatingGuiltware), even with `Date` objects (although these tend to be rounded to 100 in some very-close-to-100 cases). It also works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x1f54anp/) in the browser - anyway on my Firefox - using only `Date` objects. No idea why it behaves like this though.

Comment: It's odd that it's running short. The guarantee is that the timeout will run at or after the set time. The amount of time after is ASAP but could be a long time depending on what else is happening. What version are you using? There has been at least one [bug](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8354) like this in `setTimeout` but these are pretty old.

Comment: @Ouroborus Node.js version 8.15.1